# How to retrieve HTTP header information from a C# RESTful Service Method

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http

I have the following C# RESTful interace.

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "requires-authorization", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    string MethodRequiringAuthorization();
```

Which is implemented int the following class

```
    public string MethodRequiringAuthorization()
    {
        //var authorisazation = HTTP header authorization field
        return "{Message" + ":" + "You-accessed-this-message-with-authorization" + "}";
    }
```

I would like to pass into this method the value of the field "Authorization" in the http header (as described in the commented line). Any ideas how I can retrieve this value

Comment: maybe using `this.Request` ?

Comment: ps: you may find this useful http://forums.asp.net/p/1193533/2056217.aspx

Comment: Considering the attributes he uses above his method declaration it is safe to assume he uses WCF Rest instead of ASP.NET Web API. This means the `Request` property is not present.

Comment: Yeah it didnt really help but cheers for looking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get what I was looking for using the HttpContext.Current property. Using the Request.Headers property I was able to retrieve a name value list of the header information

```
    public string MethodRequiringAuthorization()
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        NameValueCollection headerList = httpContext.Request.Headers;
        var authorizationField = headerList.Get("Authorization");            
        return "{Message" + ":" + "You-accessed-this-message-with-authorization" + "}";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

`Request.Headers["Authorization"]`

Comment: I tried that from lookng at another post, but i dont have that option (Request.Headers) in scope.

Answer (score -1):

Quick translation of @beaumondo into VB .Net, which for some reason I've been using again for the last few months.

```
Private Function GetAuthorizationFromHeader() As String
    Dim currentContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    Dim headerList As NameValueCollection = currentContext.Request.Headers
    Dim authorizationField As String = headerList.Get("Authorization")
    Return authorizationField '"{Message" + ":" + "You-accessed-this-message-with-authorization" + "}"message-with-authorization" + "}"
End Function
```

Thank you so much, I don't know why I couldn't find about HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers easier before.

Comment: While this may be accurate, the question doesn't ask for vb.net. it asks for c#. No one looking for vb.net will find this, since the lack of the tag will exclude this question from the search results.